# How to link the textview to my XML layout

Tags: android, android-layout

im making a random fact generator and ive got the code sorted but i want it to appear with my layout in the xml file, the code i have is as follows

```
public class facts extends Activity {

//implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.facts);
    setTitle("Buy - Find a carpool!");



    Random generator= new Random();
    int num;
    String[] quotes;
    quotes= new String[15];
    quotes[0]= "test1)";
    quotes[1]= "test2";
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    num=generator.nextInt(15);
    tv.setText(quotes[num]);
    setContentView(R.layout.facts);
```

My XML code is

```
      <TextView
 android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
 android:id="@+id/factslist"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android.layout_column="15" 
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you create a TextView in code:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
```

Why not have a TextView in your .xml file (facts.xml)?  Perhaps I don't understand your question.  Can you clarify what you mean by "i want it to appear with my layout in the xml file".

If you mean you want the TextView defined in .xml, then add a `<TextView>` element to the file facts.xml:

```
   <xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hello, I am a TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So instead of this code:

```
Random generator= new Random();
int num;
String[] quotes;
quotes= new String[15];
quotes[0]= "test1)";
quotes[1]= "test2";
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
num=generator.nextInt(15);
tv.setText(quotes[num]);
setContentView(R.layout.facts);
```

You should have:

```
Random generator= new Random();
int num;
String[] quotes;
quotes= new String[15];
quotes[0]= "test1)";
quotes[1]= "test2";

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.factslist);

num=generator.nextInt(15);
tv.setText(quotes[num]);
```

Do you see how you are obtaining a reference to the TextView in you .xml file based in its id, and then setting the value of this id? I also don't think you need to call this twice:

```
setContentView(R.layout.facts);
```

Comment: Sorry im using a tutorial aswell to do this i should have mentioned, How do i go about changing it so it references my textview ID in the .xml layout?

Comment: I have the text view set up, however if i leave the android:text empty, nothing shows up, and if i enter something, it overrides the script which shows a random quote

Comment: The new code is the same, apart from the following line   TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.factslist); ive updated my original post with the XML

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: [Declaring Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html). You have to use findViewById() to get an instance of your TextView. Don't instantiate it yourself. And also, you don't have to setContentView again after changing things.

Comment: Ok i got rid of the last setcontentview part, Sorry im new to this, where do i add the findViewById(R.id.my_button);? do i have to change the textview to something else in my .xml

Comment: Ive got that all set up, but it seems that I have to enter something for the android:text=" " section, because if i dont, nothing shows up. If i do enter some text, it overrides the java code and doesnt show a random quote

Answer (score 1):

You put the TextView in your facts.xml file and then use...

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Ive changed that, now i understand that bit! But its not showing the text still